# Jest mock module multiple times with different values

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function that I want to test and this function uses an imported module:

```
var a = require('./a');

function add(b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = add;
```

That `a` module returns a number in this sample, but in my real project I use that as a config object that is changed from time to time manually.

```
var a = 1;
module.exports = a;
```

The test for the `add` function looks like this:

```
describe('add', () => {

  it('should add the mock number 1 to 2', () => {
    jest.setMock('./a', 1);
    const add = require('./add');
    expect(add(2)).toBe(3);
  });

  it('should add the mock number 2 to 2', () => {
    jest.setMock('./a', 2);
    const add = require('./add');
    expect(add(2)).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

First test passes, The second test fails because it inherits from the first mock. Is there any way to mock the `a` module multiple times?

I would like a solution that doesn't imply refactoring the `add` function and instead focus on mocking that module multiple times. (in my real project that is a config file)

You can play around with the code here: https://repl.it/@adyz/NocturnalBadComma

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
});
```

Final tests

```
describe('add', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    it('should add the mock number 5 to 2', () => {
        jest.setMock('./a', 5);
        const add = require('./add');
        expect(add(2)).toBe(7);
    });

    it('should add the mock number 2 to 2', () => {
        jest.setMock('./a', 2);
        const add = require('./add');
        expect(add(2)).toBe(4);
    });
});
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/TrustingBelatedProprietarysoftware

Comment: Perfect answer, Have save my huge time

Comment: this case is practical when we need to reset all modules, but imagine we need to reset a single module between differet 'it' blocks to change return values but keep all other mocks, is there a good solution for that case? jest.isolateModules seems not doing the stuff with default exports, also jest.doMock

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Gigi's solution, I created another example, using jest.mock:

In the file multiplier.ts, `multiplier` is the exported function we want to test:

```
  // file: multiplier.ts

  import {getNumber} from './get-number'
  const multiplier = (num:number) => num * getNumber()
  export {multiplier}
```

In the file get-number.ts, `getNumber` is the module we want to mock:

```
  // file: get-number.ts

  const getNumber = () => 2
  export {getNumber}
```

Here is the test:

```
  // file: multiplier.test.ts

  // import { multiplier } from "./multiplier"  // <-- this will not work
  
  describe("[multiplier]", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.resetModules()
    })
  
    it('should mock getNumber so that getNumber return 3', () => {
      const mockReturn = 3
  
      jest.mock( './get-number', () => (
        { getNumber: jest.fn(()=>mockReturn) }
      ))
  
      const { multiplier } = require('./multiplier')
      expect(multiplier(2)).toBe(6)
    })
  
    it('should mock getNumber so that getNumber return 4', () => {
      const mockReturn = 4
  
      jest.mock( './get-number', () => (
        { getNumber: jest.fn(()=>mockReturn) }
      ))
  
      const { multiplier } = require('./multiplier')
      expect(multiplier(2)).toBe(8)
    })
  
    it('should mock getNumber so that getNumber return 5', () => {
      const mockReturn = 5
  
      jest.mock( './get-number', () => (
        { getNumber: jest.fn(()=>mockReturn) }
      ))
  
      const { multiplier } = require('./multiplier')
      expect(multiplier(2)).toBe(10)
    })
  })
```

Note: for this to work, we need to use require to import `multiplier.ts`

Comment: That example taught me a lot about Jest! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**For callback functions, working approach is-**

```
const { validate } = require("../../controllers/..")

describe('Party Authentication', () => {
    afterEach(() => { jest.resetModules(); });

    it('should return success response', async () => {
        let req = {}
        req['headers'] = {}
        req['body'] = {}
        jest.mock('../../config/database', () => ({
            execute: (param1, param2, param3, callback) => callback(null, [{ return: 1, party_guid: "20090911093921694613", policy_guid: '20090911093921422222' }])
        }));

        const data = await validate(req)
        expect(data.status).toBe(true)
        expect(data).toHaveProperty('insuredGuid')
        expect(data.insuredGuid).toBeTruthy()
        expect(data).toHaveProperty('policyGuidAuthentication')
        expect(data.policyGuidAuthentication).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('should return response with error code and message', async () => {
        let req = {}
        req['headers'] = {}
        req['body'] = {}
        jest.mock('../../config/database', () => ({
            execute: (param1, param2, param3, callback) => callback(null, [{ return: 0, error_message: "Segurado não foi localizado com a Guid informada", error_code: 5684 }])
        }));

        const data = await validate(req)
        console.log("datadatadatadatadata", data)
        expect(data.status).toBe(false)
        expect(data).toHaveProperty('error')
        expect(data.error).toBeTruthy()

    })
})
```