# How do I mock a return value multiple times with different values in the same test?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I've built a module that searches for files using [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

```js
// fileCollector.js
const glob = require('glob');

exports.getFiles = (directory) => {
  return {
    freeMarker: glob.sync(directory + '/**/*.ftl'),
    sass: glob.sync(directory + '/**/*.scss')
  };
};
```

I'm attempting to write a test so that I can verify that:

1. Glob was called twice with the correct arguments
2. The return value of `getFiles` is correct

```js
// fileCollector.test.js
const glob = require('glob');
const fileCollector = require('fileCollector');

jest.mock('glob');

describe('getFiles', () => {
  it('should get files', () => {
    const files = fileCollector.getFiles('/path/to/files');

    expect(glob.sync.mock.calls).toEqual([['/path/to/files/**/*.ftl'], ['/path/to/files/**/*.scss']]);
    expect(files).toEqual({
      freeMarker: 'INSERT_MOCKED_VALUE_FROM_GLOB',
      sass: 'INSERT_MOCKED_VALUE_FROM_GLOB'
    });
  });
});
```

How do I mock the return value of glob twice with two separate return values so that I can test the return value of `getFiles`?

---

**Note:** [Jest mock module multiple times with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769025/11809808) does not answer my question because it mocks a different value once in separate  tests.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `mockReturnValueOnce` function twice. For example:

```js
glob.sync
  .mockReturnValueOnce(['path/to/file.ftl'])
  .mockReturnValueOnce(['path/to/file.sass']);
```

Full example:

```js
// fileCollector.test.js
const glob = require('glob');
const fileCollector = require('fileCollector');

jest.mock('glob');

describe('getFiles', () => {
  it('should get files', () => {
    glob.sync
      .mockReturnValueOnce(['path/to/file.ftl'])
      .mockReturnValueOnce(['path/to/file.sass']);

    const files = fileCollector.getFiles('/path/to/files');

    expect(glob.sync.mock.calls).toEqual([['/path/to/files/**/*.ftl'], ['/path/to/files/**/*.scss']]);
    expect(files).toEqual({
      freeMarker: ['path/to/file.ftl'],
      sass: ['path/to/file.sass']
    });
  });
});
```

*Source:* [Jest - Mock Return Values](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values)

Comment: It worked for me!

Comment: Incredible, thanks for this! I was chain `mockResolvedValue` but never thought to try `mockResolvedValueOnce` and it worked!